# Is it a bad practice to use break in a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, break

Is it a bad practice to use **`break` statement** inside a **`for` loop**?

Say, I am searching for an value in an array. Compare inside a for loop and when value is found, `break;` to exit the for loop.

Is this a bad practice? I have seen the alternative used: define a variable `vFound` and set it to true when the value is found and check `vFound` in the `for` statement condition. But is it necessary to create a new variable just for this purpose?

I am asking in the context of a normal C or C++ for loop.

P.S: The [MISRA coding guidelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) advise against using break.

Comment: Don't place `break` in the same league as `goto` :)

Comment: Er, I haven't placed them in the same league as go to...MISRA rules specify break, if I remember correctly.

Comment: The only reason I can think of to not use break inside a loop is when you still have to process more items that might change the outcome of what you are doing...

Comment: MISRA rules have been relaxed: http://www.misra.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=298

Comment: Who needs goto when you've got break label? <3 Java

Comment: @Raven: who needs break label when you have continuations and dynamic-wind? <3 Scheme

Comment: I'd only consider not breaking if the loop is for each( object in list ){} as this implies the code inside the loop should apply to all the objects equally.

Comment: Duplicated: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/58253/72317

Comment: @user724198. Exactly. Closed as not constructive even though it has a ton of upvotes and answers. I see it all the same. Extremely annoying and pathetic.

Comment: tbh, in most instances I've seen it, I can't understand why was it used inside a for, instead of using a while that checks for that condition AND the for condition. I agree that it depends on the case, but in most cases, isn't it kinda like substituting another functionality? As @e.James said, it's a problem only for  long loops, whilst it can be used in shorter ones. Which is ok, but that isn't scalable to the general case. I couldn't see it in a theorem, as its result seems to be depending on heuristics. You can use it; but why, if it's replaceable by something more "structural-friendly"?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Lots of answers here, but I haven't seen this mentioned yet:

Most of the "dangers" associated with using `break` or `continue` in a for loop are negated if you write tidy, easily-readable loops. If the body of your loop spans several screen lengths and has multiple nested sub-blocks, yes, you could easily forget that some code won't be executed after the break. If, however, the loop is short and to the point, the purpose of the break statement should be obvious.

If a loop is getting too big, use one or more well-named function calls within the loop instead. The only real reason to avoid doing so is for processing bottlenecks.

Comment: Quite true. Of course if the loop is so big and complex that it's difficult to see what's happening inside it, that's a problem whether you have a break or not.

Comment: Another issue is that break and continue cause problems with refactoring. This might be a sign that this is a bad practice. The intent of the code is also clearer when using if statements.

Comment: Those "well-named function call(s)" can be locally-defined lambda functions instead of externally-defined private functions that won't be used elsewhere.

Comment: I always say: if you're function is small, there is no such thing as an early return. This also counts for loops and breaks, I guess.

Answer (score 155):

No, break is the correct solution.

Adding a boolean variable makes the code harder to read and adds a potential source of errors.

Comment: agreed. Especially if you are looking to exit the loop under more than a single condition. The boolean to leave a loop can get really confusing then.

Comment: That is why I use `goto` to break out of Level 2+ nested loops - because there is not `break(level)`

Comment: I'd rather put the loop code in a function, and just return. This avoids the goto, and breaks your code into smaller chunks.

Answer (score 56):

You can find all sorts of professional code with 'break' statements in them. It perfectly make sense to use this whenever necessary. In your case this option is better than creating a separate variable just for the purpose of coming out of the loop.

Answer (score 54):

Using `break` as well as `continue` in a `for` loop is perfectly fine.

It simplifies the code and improves its readability.

Comment: Yes.. For a time I didn't like the idea and coded around it, but it didn't take long before I realized the... "workaround" was often a maintenance nightmare.  Well, not a nightmare, but more error-prone.

Answer (score 25):

Far from bad practice, Python (and other languages?) extended the [`for` loop](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) structure so part of it will *only* be executed if the loop *doesn't* `break`.

```
for n in range(5):
    for m in range(3):
        if m >= n:
            print('stop!')
            break
        print(m, end=' ')
    else:
        print('finished.')
```

Output:

```
stop!
0 stop!
0 1 stop!
0 1 2 finished.
0 1 2 finished.
```

---

Equivalent code without `break` and that handy `else`:

```
for n in range(5):
    aborted = False
    for m in range(3):
        if not aborted:
            if m >= n:
                print('stop!')
                aborted = True
            else:            
                print(m, end=' ')
    if not aborted:
        print('finished.')
```

Comment: Oooh, I like that and have sometimes wished for it in C.  Nice syntax too, which could be adapted into a future C-like language without ambiguity.

Comment: "C-like language" :P

Answer (score 18):

General rule: If following a rule requires you to do something more awkward and difficult to read then breaking the rule, then break the rule.

In the case of looping until you find something, you run into the problem of distinguishing found versus not found when you get out. That is:

```
for (int x=0;x<fooCount;++x)
{
  Foo foo=getFooSomehow(x);
  if (foo.bar==42)
    break;
}
// So when we get here, did we find one, or did we fall out the bottom?
```

So okay, you can set a flag, or initialize a "found" value to null. But

That's why in general I prefer to push my searches into functions:

```
Foo findFoo(int wantBar)
{
  for (int x=0;x<fooCount;++x)
  {
    Foo foo=getFooSomehow(x);
    if (foo.bar==wantBar)
      return foo;
  }
  // Not found
  return null;
}
```

This also helps to unclutter the code. In the main line, "find" becomes a single statement, and when the conditions are complex, they're only written once.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to say. Often when I find myself using `break`, I try to find some way to refactor the code into a function, so that I can use `return` instead.

Comment: I agree 100% with you, there is nothing inherently wrong with using break. However, it generally indicates that the code it is in may need to be extracted out into a function where break would be replaced with return. It should be considered a 'code smell' rather than an outright mistake.

Comment: Your answer might prompt some to explore the advisability of using [multiple return statements](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36707/1497596).

Comment: @DavidRR Personally I think a rule against multiple returns is a bad idea. Because usually it means that you have to set flags and break loops, and then at the bottom test the flags to decide what value to return. If you have a very long and complex function, having a return in the middle might be confusing because the reader may not realize it's there. But most of the time, I think avoiding having multiple returns results in uglier code than having multiple returns.

Answer (score 16):

There is nothing inherently wrong with using a break statement but nested loops can get confusing.  To improve readability many languages ([at least Java does](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)) support breaking to labels which will greatly improve readability.

```
int[] iArray = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int[] jArray = new int[]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

// label for i loop
iLoop: for (int i = 0; i < iArray.length; i++) {

    // label for j loop
    jLoop: for (int j = 0; j < jArray.length; j++) {

        if(iArray[i] < jArray[j]){
            // break i and j loops
            break iLoop;
        } else if (iArray[i] > jArray[j]){  
            // breaks only j loop
            break jLoop;
        } else {
            // unclear which loop is ending
            // (breaks only the j loop)
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I will say that break (and return) statements often increase [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) which makes it harder to prove code is doing the correct thing in all cases.

If you're considering using a break while iterating over a sequence for some particular item, you might want to reconsider the data structure used to hold your data.  Using something like a Set or Map may provide better results.

Comment: +1 for cyclomatic complexity.

Comment: .NET programmers might want to explore the use of LINQ as a potential [alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[linq]+for+loop) to complex `for` loops.

Answer (score 15):

**break** is a completely acceptable statement to use (so is **continue**, btw). It's all about code readability -- as long as you don't have overcomplicated loops and such, it's fine.

It's not like they were the same league as **goto**. :)

Comment: I have seen it argued that a break statement *is* effectively a **goto**.

Comment: The problem with goto is that you can point it anywhere. Both break and continue preserve the modularity of the code.  That argument is on the same level as having a single exit point for each function.

Comment: I've heard it argued that having multiple exit points for a function *is* effectively a **goto**. ;D

Comment: @glenatron The problem with goto isn't the goto statement, it is the introduction of the label that the goto jumps to that is the problem. Whem you read a goto statement, there is no uncertainty about control flow. When you read a label, there is lots of uncertainty about control flow (where are all the gotos that transfer control to this label?). A break statement doesn't introduce a label, so it doesn't introduce any new complications.

Comment: I quite agree. The first comment was mostly because I have seen that argument and it made me smile, then the second comment because I have also seen that argument and it was a great setup. As everyone knows, the correct way to handle these kind of control flow matters is to throw an exception and allow it to be caught in some byzantine exception handling system. Much less confusing. ;p

Comment: The "break" is a specialzied goto that can only leave blocks.  The historical problems with "goto" were (1) it could be, and often was, used to construct overlapping loop blocks in a way that isn't possible with proper control structures; (2) a common way to do an "if-then" construct which was usually "false" was to have the true case branch off to an unrelated place in the code, and then branch back.  This would cost two branches in the rare case, and zero in the common case, but it made the code look hideous.

Comment: An IF statement is effectively a GOTO. :-)

Comment: I never saw goto as different than a function call... At least, that's how I've written mine in the handful of custom batch files I've made for myself. Like "goto my_function", run some stuff, then send it right back. Sure, you *could* make it terrible, but who's fault would that be?

Answer (score 14):

It depends on the language. While you can possibly check a boolean variable here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100 && stayInLoop; i++) { ... }
```

it is not possible to do it when itering over an array:

```
for element in bigList: ...
```

Anyway, `break` would make both codes more readable.

Answer (score 8):

I agree with others who recommend using `break`.  The obvious consequential question is why would anyone recommend otherwise?  Well... when you use break, you skip the rest of the code in the block, and the remaining iterations.  Sometimes this causes bugs, for example:

- a resource acquired at the top of the block may be released at the bottom (this is true even for blocks inside `for` loops), but that release step may be accidentally skipped when a "premature" exit is caused by a `break` statement  (in "modern" C++, "RAII" is used to handle this in a reliable and exception-safe way: basically, object destructors free resources reliably no matter how a scope is exited)
- someone may change the conditional test in the `for` statement without noticing that there are other delocalised exit conditions
- ndim's answer observes that some people may avoid `break`s to maintain a relatively consistent loop run-time, but you were comparing `break` against use of a boolean early-exit control variable where that doesn't hold

Every now and then people observing such bugs realise they can be prevented/mitigated by this "no breaks" rule... indeed, there's a whole related strategy for "safer" programming called "structured programming", where each function is supposed to have a single entry and exit point too (i.e. no goto, no early return).  It may eliminate some bugs, but it doubtless introduces others.  Why do they do it?

- they have a development framework that encourages a particular style of programming / code, and they've statistical evidence that this produces a net benefit in that limited framework, or
- they've been influenced by programming guidelines or experience within such a framework, or
- they're just dictatorial idiots, or
- any of the above + historical inertia (relevant in that the justifications are more applicable to C than modern C++).

Comment: Well, yeah, but then again I've seen bugs in code by people who religiously tried to avoid `break`. The did avoid it but failed to think through the conditions that replaced the use of break.

Answer (score 6):

In your example you do not know the number of iterations for the **for** loop. Why not use **while** loop instead, which allows the number of iterations to be indeterminate at the beginning?

It is hence not necessary to use **break statemement** in general, as the loop can be better stated as a **while** loop.

Comment: A "for" loop is often good if there's a known maximum number of iterations.  That having been said, a while(1) loop is sometimes better in a scenario where one is searching for an item and plans to create it if it doesn't exist.  In that case, if the code finds the item it does a direct break, and if it hits the end of the array it creates a new item and then does a break.

Comment: In the example given -- searching through an array for a key, the for loop is the proper idiomatic construct.  You don't use a while loop to walk through an array.  You use a for loop. (or a for-each loop if available). You do this as a courtesy to other programmers, as they recognize the "for (int i=0; i < ra.length; i++){}" construct immediately as "Walk through the array"  Adding a break, to this construct is simply a "Quit early if you can" statement.

Answer (score 6):

It's perfectly valid to use `break` - as others have pointed out, it's nowhere in the same league as `goto`.

Although you might want to use the `vFound` variable when you want to check outside the loop whether the value was found in the array. Also from a maintainability point of view, having a common flag signalling the exit criteria might be useful.

Answer (score 5):

In the embedded world, there is a lot of code out there that uses the following construct:

```
    while(1)
    { 
         if (RCIF)
           gx();
         if (command_received == command_we_are_waiting_on)
           break;
         else if ((num_attempts > MAX_ATTEMPTS) || (TickGet() - BaseTick > MAX_TIMEOUT))
           return ERROR;
         num_attempts++;
    }
    if (call_some_bool_returning_function())
      return TRUE;
    else
      return FALSE;
```

This is a very generic example, lots of things are happening behind the curtain, interrupts in particular.  Don't use this as boilerplate code, I'm just trying to illustrate an example.

My personal opinion is that there is nothing wrong with writing a loop in this manner as long as appropriate care is taken to prevent remaining in the loop indefinitely.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? It looks to me as if the loop does absolutely nothing... unless there are `continue` statements inside the application logic. Are there?

Comment: continue statements are unnecessary as you are already bound by an infinite loop.  You basically perform the necessary logic required to achieve a goal and if that goal is not met in n number of attempts or a timeout condition expires, you exit the loop via a break construct and take corrective action or inform the calling code of an error.  I see this type of code often in uCs that communicate via a common bus (RS-485, etc.)  You basically attempt to seize the line and communicate without collisions, if collisions happen, you wait a duration determined by a random number and try again.

Comment: Conversely, if things go well, you also use the break statement to exit once the condition has been met.  Given this case, the code following the loop is executed and everyone is happy.

Comment: "if (call_some_bool_returning_function())
      return TRUE;
    else
      return FALSE;" could just be "return call_some_bool_returning_function()"

Answer (score 5):

I don't see any reason why it would be a bad practice PROVIDED that you want to complete STOP processing at that point.

Answer (score 5):

I did some analysis on the codebase I'm currently working on (40,000 lines of JavaScript).

**I found only 22 `break` statements,** of those:

- 19 were used inside `switch` statements (we only have 3 switch statements in total!).
- 2 were used inside `for` loops - a code that I immediately classified as to be refactored into separate functions and replaced with `return` statement.
- As for the final `break` inside `while` loop... I ran `git blame` to see who wrote this crap!

So according to my statistics: **If `break` is used outside of `switch`, it is a code smell.**

I also searched for `continue` statements. Found none.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on your use case. There are applications where the runtime of a for loop needs to be constant (e.g. to satisfy some timing constraints, or to hide your data internals from timing based attacks).

In those cases it will even make sense to set a flag and only check the flag value AFTER all the `for` loop iterations have actually run. Of course, all the for loop iterations need to run code that still takes about the same time.

If you do not care about the run time... use `break;` and `continue;` to make the code easier to read.

Comment: If timing is important you may be better off doing some sleeps and save system resources than let the program do known-to-be-useless operations.

Answer (score 2):

On [MISRA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MISRA_C) 98 rules, that is used on my company in C dev, break statement shall not be used...

Edit : Break is  allowed in MISRA '04

Comment: Exactly why I asked this question! I find no good reason why such a rule is there as a coding guideline. Also, as everyone else here said, break; looks better.

Comment: I don't know exactly why it is forbidden (more clever person than me have thinking about it...) but break (and multiple return) are better for readability (in my opinion, but my opinions are not corporates rules...)

Comment: Uh, the MISRA rules do allow the usage of break statements : http://www.misra.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=75&t=298

Comment: We used MISRA 98 rules... It is exact that MISRA 2004 changes the rules

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse, `break;` is the solution to stop the for loop or foreach loop. I used it in php in foreach and for loop and found working.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can make sense to have your checks at the top of your for loop like so

```
for(int i = 0; i < myCollection.Length && myCollection[i].SomeValue != "Break Condition"; i++)
{
//loop body
}
```

or if you need to process the row first

```
for(int i = 0; i < myCollection.Length && (i == 0 ? true : myCollection[i-1].SomeValue != "Break Condition"); i++)
{
//loop body
}
```

This way you can have a singular body function without breaks.

```
for(int i = 0; i < myCollection.Length && (i == 0 ? true : myCollection[i-1].SomeValue != "Break Condition"); i++)
{
    PerformLogic(myCollection[i]);
}
```

It can also be modified to move Break into its own function as well.

```
for(int i = 0; ShouldContinueLooping(i, myCollection); i++)
{
    PerformLogic(myCollection[i]);
}
```

Comment: lazy coding IS professional code :)

Comment: Only if it isn't a pain in the butt to maintain :)

Comment: I tend to practice "GTFO ASAP".  That is, if I can exit a structure cleanly then I should do so as soon as possible, and as near to the condition that specifies exit.

Comment: Well that works too. I think the argument I'm trying to get across is that if you are using a for loop it doesn't hurt to use its built in functionality to make your code readable and modular. If you absolutely need to have break statements inside of your loop I would sit and have a think about why that level of complexity is needed.

Comment: Haha. Consider the fact that most people who discourage `break` argue that it's for code readability. Now look again at the crazy 5 miles long condition in the loops above...

Comment: It doesn't apply to for-each loop

Comment: @Zbyszek Have you ever done a foreach like `foreach(var a in list.Where(Condition))`?