# For Loop in C- implementation

Tags: c, for-loop

I am confused on how to complete this for loop. The mission is to read input in unix. For the input if the radius is >0 it should prompt the user each time and then if <=0 it should terminate. I am going from centimeters to square inches. My current configuration requires 2 inputs (1 prompted, 1 not) before giving output to the console. Cheers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14159

main()
{
float r, a;
  int y = 9999999;


  for(int i =0; i <y; i++){
     printf("Enter the circle's radius (in centimeters): ");
     scanf ("%f", &r);

        if(r>0){
           r=r;
       a = PI * r * r *2.54;

       printf("Its area is %3.2f square inches.\n", a);
   }  else {}
     }

  }
```

Comment: You should consider it a fatal mistake to ignore the result of `scanf`.

Comment: Actually you should divide by 2.54, not multiply, and you should do it _twice_, not once. And what's this `r=r;` business?

Comment: btw it's not allowed to declare the loop counter "i" inside the loop description. that's java-style

Comment: ^^ I am used to java, which is why even simple things in C seem unfamiliar

Comment: @PrR3; Yes, you can. Its C99 feature.

Comment: Note that `else {}` is just noise for the sake of adding noise.  It does nothing useful.

Comment: Is there some significance to the use of "C-" in your title? There actually is a language called "C--", and I've heard of a joke language called "C-", named after the grade its author received in a language design course. Your title needn't say what language you're using (the tag does that), and it should describe the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try using a while loop instead so that the question is continually prompted until the user inputs a value =>0. see if below helps (also your conversion factor was not quite right);

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14159

void main()
{
    float r, a;
    printf("Enter the cirle's radius (in centimeters):");
    scanf("%f",&r); 

    while (r>0)
    {
        a=PI*r*r*0.155; // conversion from sqcm to sqin is ~0.155
        printf("Its area is %3.2f square inches \n", a);
        printf("Enter the cirle's radius (in centimeters):");
        scanf("%f",&r);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code flow is the following:

```
for (infinite condition) {
  scan input
  if (input > 0) {
    do things
  }
  else {
    do nothing
  }
}
```

So there's no way to exit out of the loop, that's why the `break` statement exists, to force quitting an iterative block of code:

```
while (true) {
  scanf ("%f", &r);
  if (r > 0) {
    // do whatever;
  }
  else
    break;
}
```

The `break` will stop the cycle when executed, just going out of the loop.

Comment: It's not infinite; it is just shy of 10 million iterations, which is a long way off infinite in any mathematical sense.  In fact, only in the sense of 'humans won't type that many entries' is it infinite.  If the data comes from a file, 10 million lines isn't a big problem (though the count still shouldn't be hard-coded; it should be conditioned on EOF).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It's an assumption I made to simplify the problem and focus on the question itself. Actually input is parsed from `stdin` so the only break condition should be EOF as you point out.

Comment: @Jack: Not a very good assumption, it really can confuse the inexperienced reader. Stating that this loop will never finish is just plainly wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a `while loop` instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14159

main(){
    float r, a;

    int continueBool = 1;
    while(continueBool == 1){
         printf("Enter the circle's radius (in centimeters): ");
         scanf ("%f", &r);

         if(r>0){
              a = PI * r * r *2.54;
              //the above formula may be wrong, so consider trying:
              //a = PI * r * r/2.54/2.54;
              printf("Its area is %3.2f square inches.\n", a);
         }
         else{
             continueBool = 0;
         }
     }
}
```

The `break` statement *can* be dangerous if you are new to C programming, so I recommend **not** using it until you get a better understanding of C and break. If you *do* want to use `break`, then this could be your solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14159

main(){
    float r, a;

    while(1){
         printf("Enter the circle's radius (in centimeters): ");
         scanf ("%f", &r);

         if(r<=0){
             break;
         }

         a = PI * r * r *2.54;
         //the above formula may be wrong, so consider trying:
         //a = PI * r * r/2.54/2.54;
         printf("Its area is %3.2f square inches.\n", a);
     }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why `break` should be dangerous. It's perfectly fine to use it in this situation. It's readable and the duty of knowing which loop you are breaking in case of nested loops is of the programmer. Using a boolean variable when not needed is not just readable. Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922599/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-break-in-a-for-loop and avoid personal opinions when not completed by explanations.

Comment: What is the problem with `break` statement?

Comment: Break "can" be dangerous depending on programming skill level.  It seems that the open poster is new to C programming.  Getting him/her into the practice of using "break" statements over properly controlled loops is (in my opinion) a bad idea.  However, learning break is still very important (I'm not saying it's not).

Comment: Also, how can I avoid personal opinions if you are arguing readability and good/bad practices....?

Answer (score 1):

```
r=1.0f;

// break if no. of cases exhausted or r is negative or zero
for(int i =0; i < y && r > 0; i++) 
{
     printf("Enter the circle's radius (in centimeters): ");

     if( scanf ("%f", &r) == 1) // Always check for successful scanf
     {
          a = PI * r * r/2.54/2.54; //This is correct formula

          printf("Its area is %3.2f square inches.\n", a);
     } 

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
for(int i =0; i < y; i++)
{
     printf("Enter the circle's radius (in centimeters): ");
     scanf ("%f", &r);

     if(r > 0)
     {
          a = PI * r * r *2.54;

          printf("Its area is %3.2f square inches.\n", a);
     } 
     else
     {
          break;
     }
 }
```

Comment: @P0W; OK. Now it will terminate if `r <= 0`.