# Practice for breaking or returning in a loop

Tags: java, loops, return, conditional-statements, break

**Background:** I am making a chess game. It works almost completely, just missing the check for checkmate, but I am refining some code for readability, etc.
Right now, I am recoding a method I had to check the path from any piece, to another location on the board. It returns true if there is a piece blocking the path and false if there is not one.
Note: I do not need to check the spot of the last location because my game will check to make sure that you do not occupy the spot you are trying to move to.

Also note that I have researched this question and I have found that the consensus, mainly on here, is that breaking is the correct solution. This is preferred over having a boolean variable initialized outside the loop and set true or false and breaking the loop on that value. However, I have two conditions in my loop that may make my code return true or return false so I can't do that completely.

*Current Code*

```
public boolean isPathClear(Location l1, Location l2) {

    int atx = l1.getX(); 
    int aty = l1.getY(); 
    int xdiff = 0, ydiff = 0;
    int endx = l2.getX(), endy = l2.getY();

    if(l1.getX() > l2.getX()) {
        xdiff = 1;
    }
    if(l1.getX() < l2.getX()) {
        xdiff = -1;
    }
    if(l1.getY() > l2.getY()) {
        ydiff = 1;
    }
    if(l1.getY() < l2.getY()) {
        ydiff = -1;
    }

while(true) {
        atx += xdiff; 
        aty += ydiff;

        if(atx == endx && aty == endy) {
            return true 
        }

        if(board[atx][aty].getType() != ' ') {
            return false; 
        }
    }
```

**Problem:** Since breaking is the preferred method, that is what I planned to do. But, I came into a problem, if I use break in one of the if statements, it looks like I have to return in the other. Like:

```
while(true) {
        atx += xdiff; 
        aty += ydiff;

        if(atx == endx && aty == endy) {
            break;
        }

        if(board[atx][aty].getType() != ' ') {
            return false; 
        }
    }

    return true;
```

**Question:**
This seems like a sort of mix that could be confusing. So with my situation, would this still be the preferred method over this code:

```
boolean clear;

    while(true) {
        atx += xdiff; 
        aty += ydiff;

        if(atx == endx && aty == endy) {
            clear = true;
            break;
        }

        if(board[atx][aty].getType() != ' ') {
            clear = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return clear;
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `while (true)` at all, but I think I'm in the minority on that. :-)

Comment: Can you please show your whole method?
What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: why do you say is breaking the preferred method?

Comment: There is a good discussion on this entire topic here: <http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/118703/where-did-the-notion-of-one-return-only-come-from>

Comment: The question is why is `break`in Java anyway ? `break`is not mandatory for loops (but for `switch`), but it allows in some situation cleaner code by avoiding  overloading of the continuing condition. Usage of `break`is valid if you dont overstress it.

Comment: If `xdiff = Math.abs(endx-atx);`, and `atx = atx + xdiff` then won't `atx` *always* equal `endx` as long as `endx`>`atx` because of the absolute value (and same for y), therefore making the first if statement always true, really, if the piece is moving in the positive x/y direction?

Comment: @Behe, I explained what it is supposed to do. And I added the one line of code missing, the signature.

Comment: @bcorso, mainly because of this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922599/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-break-in-a-for-loop

Comment: Is this not even the whole method? `l2` and `team` aren't used

Comment: A possible problem with `return` from a loop (or anywhere else besides the end) is that if you decide to add some code later that's supposed to be executed just before your method returns, you might miss that it's returning early in other cases.  That shouldn't be a problem for a small method, and if it's bigger, maybe it should be broken up anyway.  Plus, if it's a case where some cleanup needs to be performed before returning, you can use `try`...`finally` or try-with-resources.

Comment: The thing to aim for is consistency I think. I would do the first or last example(first one, myself), but not the second. Either way, staying consistent is more reader-friendly.

Comment: @asaini007, I fixed the method. Looks like I grabbed some code from another method when I was copying/pasting. But it still doesn't change the context of the question at all.

Comment: @ajb, a lot of my professors have advised against using try... unless you are specifically working with exceptions, and even to be very wary then. What's your standing behind using try...finally?

Comment: For a mental challenging development, go for **shortest and best readable**. That would probably mean: returns. Such a discussion is a waste of time and energy for your _impetus_ to produce something nice and intellectual.

Comment: @PeterMmm, so which would you prefer in this situation? You see how much I am stressing it, I can't determine what you think of as "overstressing".

Comment: @MatthewC Did they recommend against `try`...`finally`, or just `try`?    Using `try`...`finally` has a very different purpose from `try`...`catch`, although you can combine the two.  The latter is for handling exceptions; the former is for making sure needed cleanup gets done even if the method terminates unexpectedly.  For example, if your method calls another method and that method throws a runtime exception, `finally` will make sure cleanup is done even if the exception is thrown over your method's head, so to speak.

Comment: @MatthewC P.S. whatever I said about `try`...`finally` applies to try-with-resources too.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `while(true)`, you can try to handle your actual conditions inside the `while` loop and you don't need additional `break` statements:

```
public boolean isPathClear(Location l1, Location l2) {
    int atx =  l1.getX(), aty =  l1.getY();
    int endx = l2.getX(), enxy = l2.getY();

    int xdiff = Integer.signum(endx - atx);
    int ydiff = Integer.signum(endy - aty);

    do{
        atx += xdiff;
        aty += ydiff;
    } while(!(atx == endx && aty == endy) && board[atx][aty].getType() == ' ');

    return atx == endx && aty == endy;
}
```

Comment: I can't use the ? operator in this case, although that code does look very nice. The reason it won't work is because xdiff and ydiff might be 0. If movement is along the x-axis or y-axis and not diagonally, one of them will be 0. The shortest code you could make for that case would be two more statements like `int xdiff = atx > 0 ? 0 : atx`

Comment: Also, you can do int xdiff = atx == endx ? 0: (atx > endx ? 1:-1); in a single statement, but it does start to look convoluted.

Comment: Also, I've adjusted the while loop to handle both conditions inside while().

Comment: Also, I suspect that no matter how you implement this, you'll want to change your increment step to 'atx += atx == endx ? 0:xdiff' (and similarly for y) to handle the cases where x and y don't stop at the same time.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the change to the incrementation?

Comment: Suppose atx=1, endx=2, aty=1, endy=4. Then the while loop will loop 3 times until aty == endy, and (the way it is coded now) atx will also be incremented 3 times even though it should only be incremented once.

Comment: You don't have to worry about that. All movements that are passed to this method will either be straight or diagonal. The only piece that can move in a line that is not straight or diagonal is the Knight, and I do not call this method when moving the Knight.

Comment: Ah I see, well in any case, the while loop I have now removes the needs for breaks completely and also has a single exit point.

Comment: @MatthewC if you can't use ? operator, can you use Integer.signnum ? I think that is easier to understand than the ? operator so I've edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

Mostly I'd say it's a subjective thing.

One objective advantage to your last code sample is that it gives you a single point of exit from the method, which is frequently useful for debugging. A guy I used to work with who did military software previously said it was a requirement they had to work to: A method must only have a single exit point. His claim was that it was a robustness/reliability/maintainability thing. I just like having that easy "here's where it leaves" thing.

Comment: Just because a requirement is for for military software, doesn't make that requirement a good one.  Or that it even makes sense.

Comment: @Dodd10x: No argument there. In this case, I'd say there were good reasons for it, though.

Comment: @Dodd10x, Nobody said it was a good requirement. The poster simply pointed out that one style might have one advantage in this case.

Comment: @MatthewC - TJ has since expanded on his answer, but my point was simply saying the military requires it doesn't make it correct.  In fact, many military contracts require the waterfall development model still - and I think most people on stackoverflow would argue against that.

Answer (score 1):

Use return statements.  The idea is to keep it readable and maintainable.  Just don't make different method calls inside those if statements and you will be fine.

Read this post from Bruce Eckel:  http://onthethought.blogspot.com/2004/12/multiple-return-statements.html

Another benefit of using return statements is that another programmer is less likely to come along and modify your local variable, causing an incorrect value to be returned.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it using `break` - it doesn't really matter - but I prefer this:

```
boolean notObstructed = true;
while(notObstructed) {
    atx += xdiff; 
    aty += ydiff;
    if(atx == endx && aty == endy)
        break;
    if(board[atx][aty].getType() != ' ')
        notObstructed = false;
}
return notObstructed;
```

This way there's only one return statement whose value is configured based on the `while` loop and `if` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using return in these kinds of loops as i think breaks would just be a waste.
Keep a return statement at the end of your method, and use 2 regular returns in your if statements that will either return true or false.

Also last I remember coding something similar to this, since the return type of my methods were void, i could simply use:

```
return;
```

and it would exit the loop and the method.