# Try except statement python

Tags: python, try-catch, except

I was just trying to understand Try and except statements better.I am stuck. So I was hoping if you guys could clarify. This program purely for learning.

Appreciate your input.

```
while True:
    x=int(input('enter no.->'))

    try:
        x/2
    except ValueError:
        print('try again')
    else:
        if (x/2)==1:
            break
print('program end')
```

So i wrote this program with the intention-

1. loop if x is a number
2. if it is not. then 'except' comes into play and starts again
3. if quotient is 1. STOP.

Even if I change it to

```
    x=input('enter no.->')

    try:
        int(x)/2
```

'except' works but I get 'unsupported operand type(s)' if i put in a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to convert it to an int immediately.  The try-except statement will check for errors, but only in the code that is contained in the try-except thingy.  If you enter something wrong, the int conversion will immediately fail because the input is not an integer.
Instead, put the int conversion (int(string)) into the try-except statement:

```
while True:
    x=input('enter no.->')


    try:
        x=int(x)
    except ValueError:
        print('try again')
    else:
        if (x/2)==1:
            break
print('program end')
```

The second one failed because you have to set x to the converted value, so you're basically trying to divide a string by 2.

As a note, I'm not sure how applicable this is, but my OOP professor has told me using an infinite loop and breaking/returning out of it is very bad programming practice, so you should just use a boolean value (while foo: ... ... ... foo = false).  I'm not entirely sure why, as I haven't looked it up yet.

EDIT: [Is it a bad practice to use break in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922599/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-break-in-a-for-loop)

In general, it's just how readable or error-prone you're willing to let it be.

Comment: great explanation! very useful. Just 2 questions. Writing x=int(x) vs. x=int(x)/2 in 'TRY' block should work the same right because you can't divide string with 2 anyways so it will give a ValueError.? AND why do I have to set the value of x to int type? can't i just check with int(x)?

Comment: If x is not set to the int type, python treats it as a word. Imagine dividing a word by 2! How would that be done? The int(string) function converts a string to an integer.  x=int(x)/2 in the TRY block should work the same, except if it works, your new x would already be divided by 2, so if you put x=int(x)/2 in the TRY block, you would have to remove the x/2 check in the if statement (instead: "if x==1:") because x has already been divided by 2. If it doesn't work, it will indeed give you a ValueError.

Answer (score 0):

To loop while x is a number, you could do something like this (using Try and Except):

```
num = True
while num:
   x = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
   try:
       y = int(x)/2
       num = True
   except:
       num = False

print "Done!"
```

Comment: @dma1234 is right about the coding practices.  Also, you really don't need to worry about what the quotient is, as attempting to convert a non-numeric string to an integer will always give you an error.  You could really even do away with the division if you're just looking for practice with try-except.

Comment: I am trying to practice with complex statements (not that complex obviously, according to stack overflow standards) but still trying.