# Is the break statement in Java or programming in general indispensable?

Tags: java, language-agnostic, break

Is `break` statement in Java indispensable, or even the whole "break" concept? 
A task can be achieved by having a `break` in a branch. How about if `break` is never introduced to the programming language? Can we achieve the same task?

Comment: What's wrong with my question?

Comment: We usually do not like questions that seem to be copied word by word from your assignments. You can ask such a question, but I would recommend being honest and say that it's an assignment and  - even more important - add your ideas and where you are stuck.

Comment: simply answering: Yes we can achieve same task without break, it just would require more boolean flags to get same control in program. If you remove break u also should remove continue from programming language, but think of how messy code would look with tons of flags inside.

Comment: This is not an assignment question. I am not a computer science student. I learnt programming myself. Just curious about `break` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend you to use `break` statement if it's not strict necesary it's use.

It isn't a good practise in programming (look at this: [Is it a bad practice to use break in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922599/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-break-in-a-for-loop))  and I recommend you to use another alternatives, instead of `break` that could make the same work.

For example, you can wrap your code into a loop that finish with the same condition in which you wanted to put the `break` statement.

I always try not to use this `break` statement but, for example when I have to use a `switch` I always use it. It depends of the mind of each person, some persons think that `break` statement it's necesary and another people, like me, try to avoid it.

I expect it helps you to see the concept more clearly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I also see from some sources that `break` statement is not recommended.

Comment: @kwy I'm glad that it helps to you.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you can do with `break` in Java can be accomplished using state variables instead (even the `break` on `switch` statements). So in that sense, it's dispensible.

However, the resulting state variable mess is **why** we have `break`.

Answer (score 0):

All programming can be done using only `if` statements and recursion.