# Stop it from Looping in Java

Tags: java

How can I stop it from looping? The error msg box saying about invalid username and password will keep pop out based on the numbers of user I have in my textfile, I didn't know how to solve it.

```
for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {
            if (userList.get(i).getUserID().equals(txtUserID.getText()) && userList.get(i).getPassword().equals(ptxtPassword.getText())) {
                if (userList.get(i).getUserType().equals("Administrator")) {
                    System.out.println("Welcome Admin " + userList.get(i).getName() + " (" + userList.get(i).getUserID() + ")");
                    mainMenuForm.lblUser.setText("Welcome Admin " + userList.get(i).getName() + " (" + userList.get(i).getUserID() + ")");

                    mainMenuForm.setVisible(true);

                    this.setVisible(false);

                } else if (userList.get(i).getUserType().equals("Sales Manager")) {
                    System.out.println("Welcome SM" + userList.get(i).getName());
                    mainMenuForm.lblUser.setText("Welcome SM " + userList.get(i).getName() + " (" + userList.get(i).getUserID() + ")");

                    mainMenuForm.setVisible(true);
                    mainMenuForm.lblRegistration.hide();

                    this.setVisible(false);

                } else if (userList.get(i).getUserType().equals("Purchase Manager")) {
                    System.out.println("Welcome PM" + userList.get(i).getName());
                    mainMenuForm.lblUser.setText("Welcome PM " + userList.get(i).getName() + " (" + userList.get(i).getUserID() + ")");

                    mainMenuForm.setVisible(true);
                    mainMenuForm.lblDailySales.hide();

                    this.setVisible(false);
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid User ID or Password!", "Login Error", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `break` statement, but I would advice against it. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3926229/3635692) for more information.

You have the message display inside the `for` loop. You can move it out and control wether you have found the user/password or not with a `boolean` variable. The message should be visible only once if there is no such user/password combination:

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < userList.size() && !found; i++) {
    if (userList.get(i).getUserID().equals(txtUserID.getText()) && userList.get(i).getPassword().equals(ptxtPassword.getText())) {
        found = true;
        if (userList.get(i).getUserType().equals("Administrator")) {
            System.out.println("Welcome Admin " + userList.get(i).getName() + " (" + userList.get(i).getUserID() + ")");
            mainMenuForm.lblUser.setText("Welcome Admin " + userList.get(i).getName() + " (" + userList.get(i).getUserID() + ")");

            mainMenuForm.setVisible(true);

            this.setVisible(false);

        } else if (userList.get(i).getUserType().equals("Sales Manager")) {
            System.out.println("Welcome SM" + userList.get(i).getName());
            mainMenuForm.lblUser.setText("Welcome SM " + userList.get(i).getName() + " (" + userList.get(i).getUserID() + ")");

            mainMenuForm.setVisible(true);
            mainMenuForm.lblRegistration.hide();

            this.setVisible(false);

        } else if (userList.get(i).getUserType().equals("Purchase Manager")) {
            System.out.println("Welcome PM" + userList.get(i).getName());
            mainMenuForm.lblUser.setText("Welcome PM " + userList.get(i).getName() + " (" + userList.get(i).getUserID() + ")");

            mainMenuForm.setVisible(true);
            mainMenuForm.lblDailySales.hide();

            this.setVisible(false);
        }
    }
}

// if we didn't find the user/password combination, display the error message
if(!found) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid User ID or Password!", "Login Error", JOptionPane.OK_OPTION);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To break out of loop in java, `break` is the command used.

What you want is something like this, in pseudocode:

```
credentialsCorrect = false;
loop(usersList) {
  if (correct credentials) {
    credentialsCorrect = true;
    break;
  }
}
if (credentialsCorrect) {
  showCorrectCredentialsResponse();
} else {
  showWrongCredentialsResponse();
}
```

Or even better, a map with user id as the key, so you don't need to do manual looping:

```
userData = usersMap.get(userId);
credentialsCorrect = userData != null && matches(userData, password)
if (credentialsCorrect) {
  showCorrectCredentialsResponse();
} else {
  showWrongCredentialsResponse();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you can use the `break` Keyword to break out of a loop. If you want to tidy up your code, you can replace the `if` statements with a `switch` statement, to improve readability.

Answer (score 0):

get rid of

`for (int i = 0; i < userList.size(); i++) {`

to stop it from looping for every user