# Is my code wrong?

Tags: loops, structure, conditional-statements

I'm very new at coding and I'm learning by myself the C.

I'm doing my very first exercice, I gotta creat a "game"("More or Less") which the concept is :

-Computer choose a random number between and 1 and 100.

-And we gotta guess!

-The game ends when you find the Mystery Number.

I put the function loop (do..while) and also the function (if...else) to keep the game going even if you didn't find the mystery number (unless you find!)

It's been a few days that I'm stuck with my code cause, When I debug, nothing happen (so it's a pretty good news) **BUT** when I run also **NOTHING HAPPEN**

My code is:

```
int main( int argc, char*argv[])

{

    int numberYouChoose = 0;
    int MysteryNumber = 0;
    const int MAX = 100, MIN = 1;


    printf("What's the number?\n");
    scanf("%d", &numberYouChoose);

 srand(time(NULL));
MysteryNumber = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;


do{

    printf("Boooooh Try again!");
}while(numberYouChoose != MysteryNumber);

if (numberYouChoose == MysteryNumber);
 printf("Yay you found it!\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. The control structure is wrong as Juan points out in his earlier answer. Simply changing the do-while to a while-do makes your code report 'Boooh...' before the user has even had a chance to make a guess (unless you duplicate asking for a number, which isn't a good idea.
2. In your line of code `if (numberYouChoose == MysteryNumber);` the trailing `;` is an empty statement, so the `printf` line following  will always be executed.

The following works:

```
int main( int argc, char*argv[])
{
    int numberYouChoose = 0;
    int MysteryNumber = 0;
    const int MAX = 100, MIN = 1;

    srand(time(NULL));

    MysteryNumber = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;

    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf("What's the number?\n");
        scanf("%d", &numberYouChoose);
        if (numberYouChoose == MysteryNumber)
        {
            printf("Yay you found it!\n");
            break;
        }
        printf("Boooooh Try again!");
    }

     return 0;
}
```

The `( 1 )` always evaluates to true, so, in theory this will loop forever. However, when you guess correctly, the code reports this and then the `break` causes the while loop to terminate and the code continues after the while-loop.

Comment: Hello Nick, thank you for your explanation, it's really clear and helped me a lot to understand a lot of things which was absolutely a big question mark when I made this for the first time. 
I really appreciate, I'm going to try this :)

Comment: I found it helpful to put the line `printf( "Clue: %d\n", MysteryNumber );` just before the while loop. It speeded up the testing ;)

Comment: @Nick You probably have more experience than I do but as far as I know using `break` doesn't follow good practices, am I right? I mean, wouldn't it be better to evaluate in every while iteration ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez, yes, there disadvantages to using `break`. I chose to here because the lack of a 'repeat-while-do' control structure in C means that we would be forced either to duplicate the user input (as you did) or the success test. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922599/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-use-break-in-a-for-loop

Answer (score 0):

Think like a computer and go step by step... you ask once for a number and you never ask it again so it will be stuck in your do-while forever. You need to ask every time your user fails. Change your `Do-while` to a simple `while`

```
while (numberYouChoose != MysteryNumber) {
    printf("Boooooh Try again!\n");
    printf("What's the number?\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &numberYouChoose);
}

printf("Yay you found it!\n");
```

Edit:

```
 if (numberYouChoose == MysteryNumber);
  {
    printf("Yay you found it!\n");
  }
```

This is redundant, you will exit the `while`when the user types the right number.

This would be the whole code:

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{

    int numberYouChoose = 0;
    int MysteryNumber = 0;
    const int MAX = 100, MIN = 1;


    printf("What's the number?\n");
    scanf("%d", &numberYouChoose);

    srand(time(NULL));
    MysteryNumber = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;


    while (numberYouChoose != MysteryNumber)
    {
        printf("Boooooh Try again!\n");
        printf("What's the number?\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &numberYouChoose);
    }

    printf("Yay you found it!\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Juan-carlos-rodriguez, thank you for your answer! I tried to change my code thanks to your advise and I got this now:
`code`
(...)
 srand(time(NULL));
MysteryNumber = (rand() % (MAX - MIN + 1)) + MIN;

printf("What's the number?\n");
    scanf("%d", &numberYouChoose);

   while (numberYouChoose != MysteryNumber) {
        printf("Boooooh Try again!\n");
        printf("What's the number?\n");
        scanf("%d", &numberYouChoose);
    }
if (numberYouChoose == MysteryNumber){
    printf("Yay you go it!");
}

    return 0;
}

Comment: @Ringii You are welcome, if it helped you dont forget to mark it as the answer and upvote it :)

Comment: @Ringii Take a look to my last edit. I gave you a few explanations :D No need to check if the number is right. If you leave the `while` it's because you have guessed the number

Comment: Thank you a lot!! Your explanations are really precious to me!! I will try this code right now :)